# Column name not reflecting on database

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Column name not reflecting on database

e.g.

```
[Column("some_name")]
public string name { get; set; }
```

expected result:
column name should be "some_name"

actual result:
column name is "name" instead of "some_name".

Comment: Can you please confirm which version of EF you're using? The question is tagged EF6, but it is also tagged as being ASP.NET 5, which is normally used with EF7 (but *can* use EF6).

Comment: Annotations have not been implemented yet. 
https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/1424

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data annotation support is not yet implemented on EF7. You can track the work here https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/107

Comment: Any news about it ? Can we set the column name with the Fluent API ?

Comment: Yes you can check out here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31084416/override-default-identity-table-names/31094535?noredirect=1#comment50235397_31094535