# Override Default Identity Table Names

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I would like to rename the default identity table names:

- AspNetRoles
- AspNetUserClaims
- AspNetUserLogins
- AspNetUserRoles
- AspNetUsers

I understand how to do this using EF6:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>()
            .ToTable("Users", "dbo").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("User_Id");
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .ToTable("Users", "dbo").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("User_Id");
    }
```

However I'm struggling with EF7 as the DbModelBuilder has been replaced with ModelBuilder.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Where did you find that DbModelBuilder has been replaced with ModelBuilder? I have not had a lot of success in finding what the differences are between EF6 and EF7, or where that information is kept.

Comment: Check out the github  project for asp.net 5.  This is where all the development is happening:  https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/labels/Breaking%20change

Comment: Thanks! The EF team opened an issue on github for the purpose of making sure to have a place to document these differences: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework.Docs/issues/40.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use ForSqlServer or ForRelational in the SqlServerPropertyBuilder to change the column name and in the modelBuilder to change the table name

```
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>()
                .Property(o => o.Id)
                .ForSqlServer()
                .Column("User_Id")

 modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>()
                    .ForSqlServer()
                    .Table("User")
```

---

**Update :**
For the beta 5 is not longer mandatory to use ForSqlServer

Comment: Hi @Pedro, that looks to change a column name but I want to change the table name?

Comment: Is quite the same you must use ForSqlServer modelBuilder.ForSqlServer().Table("Users"), I update the answer

Comment: Thanks, so simple - think I must have been staring at the screen to long yesterday!!

Comment: This solution did not work for Identity* classes other than IdentityUser. You need to specify explicit class i.e. IdentityUserClaims<string> instead of IdentityUserClaims to rename the tables.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works for ASP.NET MVC Core. You may ask yourself why you would want to change the default names? Well, what if you wanted to host several client sites, with their own authentication, on the same database to avoid additional hosting costs associated with having additional databases. Remember to delete the existing migration scripts and initialise with the changes. Hope this helps:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        const string

          IDENTITY_PREFIX = "CLIENT9002",


          ASP_NET_USERS = "T0001_Security_User",
          ASP_NET_ROLES = "T0002_Security_Role",
          ASP_NET_USER_ROLES = "T0003_Security_User_Role",
          ASP_NET_USER_LOGIN = "T0004_Security_User_Login",
          ASP_NET_USER_CLAIM = "T0005_Security_User_Claim",
          ASP_NET_ROLE_CLAIM = "T0006_Security_Role_Claim",

          ASP_NET_USER_TOKENS = "T0007_AspNetUserTokens"
          ;

        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        #region Change Identity Tables

        #region User
        //aside:    The PK and FK need to be renamed in the DB to avoid conflict.
        //          Also any migration scripts in future also have to be stripped of any reference to Identity Tables
        builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(entity =>
        {

            entity.HasKey(e => e.Id).HasName(string.Format("{0}_PK_{1}", IDENTITY_PREFIX, ASP_NET_USERS));
            entity.ToTable(string.Format("{0}_{1}", IDENTITY_PREFIX, ASP_NET_USERS)).Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UserId");

            entity.HasMany(r => r.Claims).WithOne().HasForeignKey(rc => rc.UserId).IsRequired().HasConstraintName(string.Format("{0}_FK_{1}_{2}", IDENTITY_PREFIX, ASP_NET_USERS, "Claims"));
            entity.HasMany(r => r.Logins).WithOne().HasForeignKey(rc => rc.UserId).IsRequired().HasConstraintName(string.Format("{0}_FK_{1}_{2}", IDENTITY_PREFIX, ASP_NET_USERS, "Logins"));
            entity.HasMany(r => r.Roles).WithOne().HasForeignKey(rc => rc.UserId).IsRequired().HasConstraintName(string.Format("{0}_FK_{1}_{2}", IDENTITY_PREFIX, ASP_NET_USERS, "Roles"));

            entity.HasMany(d => d.recipecreatedby).WithOne(p => p.ApplicationUserCreatedBy).HasForeignKey(d => d.createdby); //.IsRequired();
            entity.HasMany(d => d.recipechangedby).WithOne(p => p.ApplicationUserChangedBy).HasForeignKey(d => d.changedby);

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.NormalizedEmail).HasName(string.Format("{0}_{1}_{2}", IDENTITY_PREFIX, ASP_NET_USERS, "EmailIndex"));
            entity.HasIndex(e => e.NormalizedUserName).HasName(string.Format("{0}_{1}_{2}", IDENTITY_PREFIX, ASP_NET_USERS, "UserNameIndex"));

        }
            );
        #endregion

        #region Role
        builder.Entity<ApplicationRole>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Id).HasName(string.Format("{0}_PK_{1}", IDENTITY_PREFIX, ASP_NET_ROLES));
            entity.HasIndex(e => e.NormalizedName).HasName(string.Format("{0}_{1}_{2}", IDENTITY_PREFIX, ASP_NET_ROLES, "RoleNameIndex"));
            entity.ToTable(string.Format("{0}_{1}", IDENTITY_PREFIX, ASP_NET_ROLES));
            entity.HasMany(r => r.Claims).WithOne().HasForeignKey(rc => rc.RoleId).IsRequired().HasConstraintName(string.Format("{0}_FK_{1}_{2}", IDENTITY_PREFIX, ASP_NET_ROLES, "Claims"));
            entity.HasMany(r => r.Users).WithOne().HasForeignKey(rc => rc.RoleId).IsRequired().HasConstraintName(string.Format("{0}_FK_{1}_{2}", IDENTITY_PREFIX, ASP_NET_ROLES, "Users"));
        }
        );
        #endregion

        #region Role Claims            
        builder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<int>>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Id).HasName(string.Format("{0}_PK_{1}", IDENTITY_PREFIX, ASP_NET_ROLE_CLAIM));
            entity.ToTable(string.Format("{0}_{1}", IDENTITY_PREFIX, ASP_NET_ROLE_CLAIM));
        }
        );
        #endregion

        #region User Claims
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<int>>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Id).HasName(string.Format("{0}_PK_{1}", IDENTITY_PREFIX, ASP_NET_USER_CLAIM));
            entity.ToTable(string.Format("{0}_{1}", IDENTITY_PREFIX, ASP_NET_USER_CLAIM));
        }
        );
        #endregion

        #region User Login
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<int>>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => new { e.LoginProvider, e.ProviderKey }).HasName(string.Format("{0}_PK_{1}", IDENTITY_PREFIX, ASP_NET_USER_LOGIN)); ;
            entity.Property(e => e.LoginProvider).HasMaxLength(450);

            entity.Property(e => e.ProviderKey).HasMaxLength(450);
            entity.ToTable(string.Format("{0}_{1}", IDENTITY_PREFIX, ASP_NET_USER_LOGIN));

        });
        #endregion

        #region User Role
        builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<int>>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => new { e.UserId, e.RoleId }).HasName(string.Format("{0}_PK_{1}", IDENTITY_PREFIX, ASP_NET_USER_ROLES));
            entity.ToTable(string.Format("{0}_{1}", IDENTITY_PREFIX, ASP_NET_USER_ROLES));
        });
        #endregion


        #region Tokens

            builder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<int>>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => new { e.UserId, e.LoginProvider, e.Name }).HasName(string.Format("{0}_PK_{1}", IDENTITY_PREFIX, ASP_NET_USER_TOKENS));
                entity.ToTable(string.Format("{0}_{1}", IDENTITY_PREFIX, ASP_NET_USER_TOKENS));
            });
        #endregion

        #region Recipes
        builder.Entity<recipe>(x =>
        {
            x.HasKey(t => new { t.recipeid });
            x.HasIndex(i => new { i.slugid });
            x.HasIndex(i => new { i.name });
      //      x.HasMany(r => r.Ingredients).WithOne().HasForeignKey(rc => rc.RecipeID).IsRequired();
        });

      //  builder.Entity<Ingredients>().HasKey(t => new { t.IngredientID });

        #endregion

        #endregion

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
    builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("User");
    builder.Entity<ApplicationRole>().ToTable("Role");

    builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>().ToTable("UserRole");
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<string>>().ToTable("UserClaim");
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>().ToTable("UserLogin");

    builder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<string>>().ToTable("RoleClaim");
    builder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<string>>().ToTable("UserToken");
```

@noelbr

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd include some code (streamlined) that also shows how to rename the system tables. User Tables should already be named in their schema but can be overwritten the same way if necessary

```
 using Bhail.Models;
using Bhail.Models.Issues;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using OpenIddict.Models;

 namespace Bhail.Data
  {
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int>
{
    #region Custom/Additional Tables Created
    public DbSet<Issue> Issue { get; set; }
    public DbSet<IssueAttachments> IssueAttachments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<IssueNotes> IssueNotes { get; set; }
    //        public DbSet<IssueLeaseConditionAssignment> IssueLeaseAssignment { get; set; }
    //public DbSet<IssuePriorityType> IssuePriorityType { get; set; }
    public DbSet<IssueType> IssueType { get; set; }
    //public DbSet<Status> Status { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Lease> Lease { get; set; }
    public DbSet<LeaseCondition> LeaseCondition { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Property> Property { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PropertyUserAssignment> PropertyUserAssignment { get; set; }
    #endregion

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        const string

          IDENTITY_PREFIX = "CLIENT1000",

          ASP_NET_USER = "T0001_SECURITY_USER",
          ASP_NET_ROLE = "T0002_SECURITY_ROLE",
          ASP_NET_USER_ROLE = "T0003_SECURITY_USER_ROLE",
          ASP_NET_USER_LOGIN = "T0004_SECURITY_USER_LOGIN",
          ASP_NET_USER_CLAIM = "T0005_SECURITY_USER_CLAIM",
          ASP_NET_ROLE_CLAIM = "T0006_SECURITY_ROLE_CLAIM",
          ASP_NET_USER_TOKEN = "T0007_SECURITY_USER_TOKENS",
          OPENIDDICT_AUTHORIZATION = "T0010_SECURITY_OPENIDDICT_AUTHORIZATION",
          OPENIDDICT_APPLICATION = "T0011_SECURITY_OPENIDDICT_APPLICATION",
          OPENIDDICT_SCOPE = "T0012_SECURITY_OPENIDDICT_SCOPE",
          OPENIDDICT_TOKEN = "T0013_SECURITY_OPENIDDICT_TOKEN"
          ;

        #region Security
        #region Identity Tables
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        // Need to add the FK for the INHERITED AUDIT which is different as different tables
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(entity =>
        {

            entity.ToTable(string.Format("{0}_{1}", IDENTITY_PREFIX, ASP_NET_USER));
            entity.HasMany(d => d.issueattachmentcreatedby).WithOne(p => p.applicationusercreatedby).HasForeignKey(d => d.createdby); //.IsRequired();
            entity.HasMany(d => d.issueattachmentchangedby).WithOne(p => p.applicationuserchangedby).HasForeignKey(d => d.changedby);

            entity.HasMany(d => d.issuecreatedby).WithOne(p => p.applicationusercreatedby).HasForeignKey(d => d.createdby);
            entity.HasMany(d => d.issuechangedby).WithOne(p => p.applicationuserchangedby).HasForeignKey(d => d.changedby);

            ////#region Additional User Assignment other than Audit
            entity.HasMany(d => d.issueinspectedby).WithOne(p => p.issueinspectedby).HasForeignKey(d => d.inspectedby);
            entity.HasMany(d => d.issuecompletedby).WithOne(p => p.issuecompletedby).HasForeignKey(d => d.completedby);
            ////#endregion

            entity.HasMany(d => d.issuenotescreatedby).WithOne(p => p.applicationusercreatedby).HasForeignKey(d => d.createdby);
            entity.HasMany(d => d.issuenoteschangedby).WithOne(p => p.applicationuserchangedby).HasForeignKey(d => d.changedby);

            //entity.HasMany(d => d.prioritytypecreatedby).WithOne(p => p.applicationusercreatedby).HasForeignKey(d => d.createdby);
            //entity.HasMany(d => d.prioritytypechangedby).WithOne(p => p.applicationuserchangedby).HasForeignKey(d => d.changedby);

            entity.HasMany(d => d.issuetypecreatedby).WithOne(p => p.applicationusercreatedby).HasForeignKey(d => d.createdby);
            entity.HasMany(d => d.issuetypechangedby).WithOne(p => p.applicationuserchangedby).HasForeignKey(d => d.changedby);

            //entity.HasMany(d => d.statuscreatedby).WithOne(p => p.applicationusercreatedby).HasForeignKey(d => d.createdby);
            //entity.HasMany(d => d.statuschangedby).WithOne(p => p.applicationuserchangedby).HasForeignKey(d => d.changedby);

            entity.HasMany(d => d.leaseconditioncreatedby).WithOne(p => p.applicationusercreatedby).HasForeignKey(d => d.createdby);
            entity.HasMany(d => d.leaseconditionchangedby).WithOne(p => p.applicationuserchangedby).HasForeignKey(d => d.changedby);

            entity.HasMany(d => d.propertycreatedby).WithOne(p => p.applicationusercreatedby).HasForeignKey(d => d.createdby);
            entity.HasMany(d => d.propertychangedby).WithOne(p => p.applicationuserchangedby).HasForeignKey(d => d.changedby);

            entity.HasMany(d => d.issueleaseconditionassignmentcreatedby).WithOne(p => p.applicationusercreatedby).HasForeignKey(d => d.createdby);
            entity.HasMany(d => d.issueleaseconditionassignmentchangedby).WithOne(p => p.applicationuserchangedby).HasForeignKey(d => d.changedby);

            entity.HasMany(d => d.propertyuserassignmentcreatedby).WithOne(p => p.applicationusercreatedby).HasForeignKey(d => d.createdby);
            entity.HasMany(d => d.propertyuserassignmentchangedby).WithOne(p => p.applicationuserchangedby).HasForeignKey(d => d.changedby);



            #region Property User Assignment
            //NB: doesnt seem necessary as already defined within the table
            //entity.HasMany(d => d.propertyuserassignment).WithOne(p => p.ApplicationUser).HasForeignKey(d => d.userassignment);
            #endregion

        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationRole>().ToTable(string.Format("{0}_{1}", IDENTITY_PREFIX, ASP_NET_ROLE));
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<int>>().ToTable(string.Format("{0}_{1}", IDENTITY_PREFIX, ASP_NET_USER_CLAIM));
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<int>>().ToTable(string.Format("{0}_{1}", IDENTITY_PREFIX, ASP_NET_USER_ROLE));
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<int>>().ToTable(string.Format("{0}_{1}", IDENTITY_PREFIX, ASP_NET_USER_LOGIN));
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<int>>().ToTable(string.Format("{0}_{1}", IDENTITY_PREFIX, ASP_NET_ROLE_CLAIM));
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<int>>().ToTable(string.Format("{0}_{1}", IDENTITY_PREFIX, ASP_NET_USER_TOKEN));
        #endregion

        #region OpenIDDict
        modelBuilder.Entity<OpenIddictApplication<int>>().ToTable(string.Format("{0}_{1}", IDENTITY_PREFIX, OPENIDDICT_APPLICATION));
        modelBuilder.Entity<OpenIddictAuthorization<int>>().ToTable(string.Format("{0}_{1}", IDENTITY_PREFIX, OPENIDDICT_AUTHORIZATION));
        modelBuilder.Entity<OpenIddictScope<int>>().ToTable(string.Format("{0}_{1}", IDENTITY_PREFIX, OPENIDDICT_SCOPE));
        modelBuilder.Entity<OpenIddictToken<int>>().ToTable(string.Format("{0}_{1}", IDENTITY_PREFIX, OPENIDDICT_TOKEN));
        #endregion
        #endregion

        #region Issues
        modelBuilder.Entity<IssueLeaseConditionAssignment>().HasKey(t => new { t.issueid, t.leaseconditionid });
        modelBuilder.Entity<PropertyUserAssignment>().HasKey(t => new { t.propertyid, t.userassignment });


        #region Additional Indexes

        //aside: as checks are done on whetherh title exists, create an index for these.
        modelBuilder.Entity<Issue>().HasIndex(e => e.statusid);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Issue>().HasIndex(e => e.title);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Issue>().HasIndex(e => e.completed);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Issue>().HasIndex(e => e.prioritytypeid);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Issue>().HasIndex(e => e.issuetypeid);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Property>().HasIndex(e => e.statusid);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Property>().HasIndex(e => e.title);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Lease>().HasIndex(e => e.statusid);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Lease>().HasIndex(e => e.title);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Lease>().HasIndex(e => e.propertyid);

        modelBuilder.Entity<LeaseCondition>().HasIndex(e => e.leaseid);
        modelBuilder.Entity<LeaseCondition>().HasIndex(e => e.title);

        //modelBuilder.Entity<Status>().HasIndex(e => e.title);
        //modelBuilder.Entity<Status>().HasIndex(e => e.standard);

        modelBuilder.Entity<IssueNotes>().HasIndex(e => e.title);

        modelBuilder.Entity<IssueAttachments>().HasIndex(e => e.title);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IssueAttachments>().HasIndex(e => e.attachmenttype);
        //modelBuilder.Entity<IssuePriorityType>().HasIndex(e => e.title);
        modelBuilder.Entity<IssueType>().HasIndex(e => e.title);

        #endregion


        #endregion
    }

    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<IdentityUser>(b =>
    { 
        b.ToTable("Users", "dbo"); 
    });

    builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<string>>(b =>
    {
        b.ToTable("UserClaims", "dbo");
    });

    builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>(b =>
    {
        b.ToTable("UserLogins", "dbo");
    });

    builder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<string>>(b =>
    {
        b.ToTable("UserTokens", "dbo");
    });

    builder.Entity<IdentityRole>(b =>
    {
        b.ToTable("Roles", "dbo");
    });

    builder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<string>>(b =>
    {
        b.ToTable("RoleClaims", "dbo");
    });

    builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>(b =>
    {
        b.ToTable("UserRoles", "dbo");
    });

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Add this method inside `ApplicationDbContext` class.

> don't forget to add the last line.